# create relationship between existing nodes in Py4neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have a list of gene names `genes_list` and a list of genes that target other genes (list of tuples) `genes2`, I successfully connected to my local database and created the 20244 nodes labeled `GEN` with `name` property.
I am trying to generate a script that automates the creation of relationships for any pair of nodes(usin variables `tupla[0]and tupla[1]`) in a Neo4j graph but I can't get the for loop to work for a list of tuples, any advice? Im still learning how to use this library any advices would be great! regards!

```
from py2neo import Node,Relationship,Graph, database,NodeMatcher  
import time
import pandas as pd

genes_list=pd.read_csv("Gen_list.txt",delimiter="\t",header=None)
genes_list=genes_list[0].tolist()
for name in genes_list:
    graph.run("CREATE(:GEN{name:$name})",name=name)

genes=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\espin\OneDrive\Escritorio\MCI\SCRIPTS\dorothea_final.csv", delimiter="\t",header=None)
genes2=list(genes.to_records(index=False))

for tupla in genes2:
    existing_u1 = matcher.match("GEN").where(name=tupla[0]).first()
    existing_u2 = matcher.match("GEN").where(name=tupla[1).first()
    graph.merge(existing_u1,"REGULATES", existing_u2)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: When i run the last 4 lines i get this:  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__db_merge__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

merge = subgraph.__db_merge__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__db_merge__'
TypeError("No method defined to merge object %r" % subgraph)
TypeError: No method defined to merge object None

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, For the people that want to try this implementation and is using py2neo V4, try using graph.run()

```
for tupla in genes2:
    graph.run("MATCH(a:GEN{name:$name}) MATCH(b:GEN{name:$name1}) CREATE (a)-[:REGULATES]->(b)",name=tupla[0],name1=tupla[1])
```

remember that the query has to be in the first argument and then you declare the $`variables` separated by ","
at less this works when you have already created the nodes and does not duplicate the existing ones.